# Facebook review for iOS camera application

Tags: ios, facebook

My App has a functionality to broadcast a live stream to the user's FB page. I'm looking for the right way to **provide App for the Facebook review**.

The first officially proposed option is to `upload a simulator build file` — ios simulator doesn't provide an opportunity to get access to the Camera to test it;
the second option is `to review the app in the Apple App Store` — but not by a link for external testing but only by App ID for already released Apps.

Live broadcasting to Facebook is the main functionality of my app, and I can't release it before Facebook review my app. So what is the right way to provide App for the review?

Comment: I assume you read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-LIVE_VIDEOS and specifically the "Disallowed Usage" and "Streaming video from a mobile device camera. This feature is already available in the Facebook app"

Comment: @WizKid, yes I saw it, but how strict is it? I supposed that if in the documentation was specified the reason why it is disallowed "This feature is already available in the Facebook app" if the app has some specific feature other than just broadcast live camera stream it can be positively reviewed, isn't it? In my case App has a built-in prompter that scroll prepared script during live camera broadcasting.